# How to put parameters in to file path?

Tags: python, json, path

I have a question. I need to run program using python, but I need to run it with parameters, eg. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Program\program.exe" Param1/Param2. I have this path variable in json file (`Data.file_path`), but I don't know how to put there parameters. I tried:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Program\\Program.exe Param1/Param2"

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Program\\Program.exe" "Param1/Param2"

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Program\\Program.exe" 'Param1/Param2'

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Program\\Program.exe 'Param1/Param2'"

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Program\\Program.exe \"Param1/Param2\""

"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Program\\Program.exe --"Param1/Param2\"
```

... and everything doesn't work :( Every try is failed.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The system cannot find the file specified
```

I run it here:

```
 def programHandler(self):
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps["app"] = Data.file_path
        launcherDriver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4723',
            desired_capabilities=desired_caps)
```

Could you hel me?

Comment: The `/` can be the problem. You can try to mirror it this way: `Param1\/Param2`. And they look weird. Are you sure they shouldn't look like this `/Param1 /Param2`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found such a solution:

```
desired_caps["app"] = Data.file_path
desired_caps["appArguments"] = Data.params
```

And my json:

```
{
"file_path": ""C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Program\\Program.exe",
"params": "Param1/Param2"
}
```

Maybe it will be useful to someone :)